# In JS, do variables ever point to the same location in memory in the call stack?

Tags: javascript

```
let x = 10;
let y = x;
x = 20;
```

Will x and y point to the same location in memory for value 10, and then another location will be created for the value 20 for x. Or are x and y pointing to different location from the beginning, and the value for location x got updated to 20?

So i have a udemy course for javascript, where the guy says x and y points to the same location and then x points to another location for the new value 20. But then when i ask chatGPT it says x and y have different locations from the beginning.

Comment: In your case, they have different values. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#primitive_values

Comment: It's a copy, not a reference so it is two values. Why would it be reference till you change it and then a copy? It is 2 values from the beginning.

Comment: Hate to say it, but chatGPT is right. If however, `x` is assigned a array: `let x=[]`. Then  it would be the same pointer to the same array

Comment: if x were an object or an array then x and y would point to the same structure in memory.  With non object types that is not the case.

Comment: Realistically, an engine can indeed optimise this so both `x` and `y` point to the same memory address. Yet, that's going to be an implementation detail. The semantics of the program would stay the same in either case, so there is going to be essentially no observable difference.

Comment: I add another dupe link because the exact example is actually a particular case where (in V8) the value isn't even really stored in the heap, but inside what would usually be the pointer itself.